# Comparing VARCHARs of different length

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing a stored procedure and I need to compare a SQL Server variable to a column. The problem, is that if my SQL variable is a VARCHAR that's not the same length as the column type, it won't match.

Example:
Let's say, I have a table `types` with a column `name` that has a type `VARCHAR(100)`. Running the code below won't give me any results:

```
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(20);
SET @type = 'My Type Name';
select * from types where name = @type
```

However, running this query will find my column:

```
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(100);
SET @type = 'My Type Name';
select * from types where name = @type
```

Now, I'd like to be able to do it the first way, especially because if I modify the column, I don't want this query to start failing. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

Here's my column schema:

[image: My Schema]

Query:

```
DECLARE @event_type VARCHAR(20);
SET @event_type = 'Price Increase Notification';
select * from events.types where name = @event_type
```

Output:

[image: First output]

Query:

```
DECLARE @event_type VARCHAR(100);
SET @event_type = 'Price Increase Notification';
select * from events.types where name = @event_type
```

Output:

[image: Second output]

Comment: Can you share some sample data where you find this occurs? `'My Type Name'` in a string of length 20 is equal to `'My Type Name'` in a string of length 100. If you try to set a variable of length 20 to a value with a greater length, it gets truncated, and you may get unexpected results.

Comment: When the input `'My Type Name'` is more than 20 characters then the first will fail .It will truncate the input to 20 characters and validate against `name`. It will not throw any exception or warning

Comment: Updated the question with examples.

Comment: @snyderxc Clearly length of `'Price Increase Notification'` is greater than `20` so in first query `@event_type` will hold just first 20 characters `'Price Increase Notif'` so you are not getting expected result

Comment: Yeah, "clearly" I overlooked that ;) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will behave as you described:

```
CREATE TABLE #types
(
    type VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #types (type) VALUES ('My Type Name')

-- returns 1 row
select * from #types

-- returns 0 rows
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10);
SET @type = 'My Type Name';
select * from #types where type = @type

-- returns 1 row
DECLARE @long_type VARCHAR(100);
SET @long_type= 'My Type Name';
select * from #types where type = @long_type

drop table #types
```

The point is that `DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10); SET @type = 'My Type Name';` will actually set your variable to `'My Type Na'` (length = 10).

So, if your value is longer than your variable, the variable is set to the truncated value. No warning, no error. If you then try to equate it to the original (longer) value, you'll find they aren't equal.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. I was using a string longer than 20 characters, and it was getting truncated. Thanks a lot! I also really wish that SQL Server would give you a warning, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Your edited example:

```
DECLARE @event_type VARCHAR(20);
SET @event_type = 'Price Increase Notification';
select * from events.types where name = @event_type
```

The string you are setting @event_type to is 27 characters so it is getting truncated to the 20 characters and therefore there is no match.

What I would probably do to ensure if the column length changes you are ok is declare @event_type as varchar(max)

Answer (score 0):

here is what I would do 
select * from events.types where ltrim(rtrim(name)) = @event_type